# File save into mysql data type TEXT

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to upload file using php, mysql to mysql db, but my db field is of type TEXT, can I uploda any type of file to this field?

Comment: Do you want to save the filepath, or file contents to the db? The former is fine - for the latter you will need blob type

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot upload a **file** to MYSQL, but you can either upload it's contents or it's path and then read it with PHP.

Comment: could you please brief me how could I achieve that?

Comment: It depends on solely on the type of file on your hands and if PHP is able to read it. For example a text file can be opened, read and closed in PHP. You can read it's contents and insert it into your database. If you were to upload a file path, you can then create a simple link to the file for the user to open in their browser. An example: You have a .docx file. You can find plugins to read .docx file contents, but it might be hard. So the best thing is to get the file path in your server and store it in the database, then create a link for it. I cannot explain this more specifically im afraid

Comment: Files are stored in your server. Numbers and characters are stored inside a database.